# How to make 2 Visual Studio C++ settings identical and remove managed targeted code assembling error?

Tags: c++, .net, visual-studio-2010

I have 2 very similar projects (concole Visual C++) but in one of them in the Release Mode I am getting the error:

managed targeted code requires a '/clr' option

I am comparing the Properties C/C++ command line:
The error Project:

/Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oy- /GL /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm- /MT /GS- /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\airl.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll" /analyze- /errorReport:queue

The No Error (good) Project

/Zi /nologo /W3 /WX- /O2 /Oy- /GL /D "WIN32" /D "NDEBUG" /D "_CONSOLE" /D "_UNICODE" /D "UNICODE" /Gm- /EHsc /MT /GS /fp:precise /Zc:wchar_t /Zc:forScope /Fp"Release\prj.pch" /Fa"Release\" /Fo"Release\" /Fd"Release\vc100.pdb" /Gd /analyze- /errorReport:queue

There are a few differences, but I do not know how to remove

/FU"C:\Program Files (x86)\Reference Assemblies\Microsoft\Framework.NETFramework\v4.0\System.Core.dll"

What about Gd option in the good configuration?

Comment: Use the "References" selection in Project Properties, remove the reference to System.Core.dll   And "exception" is not the right term for a compile error.

Comment: I did not find the reference to System.core.dll in "References"

Comment: They are not similar projects.  And yes, you have to use /clr for a C++/CLI project.  The usual mistake is making changes in the Debug configuration and forgetting to make them as well in the Release configuration.  Switch back to Debug, look at the settings shown in **bold** type.